# What is on Steve Rogers' list of things to watch?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In the opening scenes of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, we get a quick glimpse at a list of things Steve Rogers wants to catch up on since he was frozen.

I read that these things were region specific, but never really saw much more than that.

I just watched it and noticed that in the Australian cut Steve wants to see "Skippy the Bush Kangaroo" and Rocky (although perhaps not Rocky 2).

**Is there a complete list of all the 'stuff' from the different cuts that the Captain wants to catch up on?**

And which things are on all lists?

Comment: Skippy the Bush Kangaroo is by far my favorite show I've never seen, thanks entirely to Craig Ferguson.

Answer (score 90):

**TL;DR**

Across the multiple versions of the lists, the last five items of each list match between each region.

- [Thai Food](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_cuisine)
- [Star Wars](http://www.starwars.com)/[Trek](http://www.startrek.com)
- [Nirvana (Band)](http://www.nirvana.com)
- [Rocky](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075148/) ([Rocky II?](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079817/?ref_=nv_sr_2))
- [Troubleman (Soundtrack)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trouble_Man_%28album%29)

Screenshots come from the “Steve Rogers’ Notebook” featurette on the DVD special features.

---

### So what are the differences?

According to [Entertainment Weekly](http://popwatch.ew.com/2014/04/01/captain-america-country-lists/), there are 10 different regional versions of the list.

> Empire magazine tweeted out the list for the U.K., but the studio actually has specific lists for 10 different markets, including France, Germany, Italy, and Korea.

However, I have found evidence of 11 lists.

### US

- [I Love Lucy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043208/)
- [Moon Landing](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/apollo/apollo11.html#.VNoN8HZj-EI)
- [Berlin Wall (Up + Down)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Wall)
- [Steve Jobs (Apple)](http://www.biography.com/people/steve-jobs-9354805)
- [Disco](http://www.discomusic.com/)
- Thai Food
- Star Wars/Trek
- Nirvana (Band)
- Rocky (Rocky II?)
- Troubleman (Soundtrack)

[image: American edition]

---

### UK

- [TV Show - Sherlock](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1475582/)
- Moon Landing
- [The Beatles](http://www.thebeatles.com/)
- [World Cup Final (1966)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1966_FIFA_World_Cup_Final)
- [Sean Connery](http://www.biography.com/people/sean-connery-9255144)
- Thai Food
- Star Wars/Trek
- Nirvana (Band)
- Rocky (Rocky II?)
- Troubleman (Soundtrack)

[image: UK edition]

---

### Korea

- [Dance Dance Revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dance_Dance_Revolution)
- [Ji-Sung Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Park_Ji-sung)
- [Oldboy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0364569/)
- [2002 World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup)
- Disco
- Thai Food
- Star Wars/Trek
- Nirvana (Band)
- Rocky (Rocky II?)
- Troubleman (Soundtrack)

[image: Korean edition]

---

### Spain

- [Rafa Nadal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rafael_Nadal)
- [Chupa Chups](http://www.chupachups.com/homepage.html)
- [Héroes del Silencio](http://heroesdelsilencio.es/)
- [1978 Constitution](http://www.tribunalconstitucional.es/en/constitucion/Pages/ConstitucionIngles.aspx)
- [Camilo José Cela](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/literature/laureates/1989/cela-facts.html)
- Thai Food
- Star Wars/Trek
- Nirvana (Band)
- Rocky (Rocky II?)
- Troubleman (Soundtrack)

[image: Spanish edition]

---

### Latin America

- [Chilean Miners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_Copiap%C3%B3_mining_accident)
- [Maradona's Hand of God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentina_v_England_%281986_FIFA_World_Cup%29#.22Hand_of_God.22_goal)
- [Shakira](http://www.shakira.com)
- [Neri Vela (1st Mexican Astronaut)](http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/Bios/htmlbios/nerivela-r.html)
- [Octavio Paz (Nobel Winner)](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/literature/laureates/1990/paz-bio.html)
- Thai Food
- Star Wars/Trek
- Nirvana (Band)
- Rocky (Rocky II?)
- Troubleman (Soundtrack)

[image: Latin American edition]

---

### Italy

- [World Cup Championship – 1982](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_FIFA_World_Cup), [2006](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_FIFA_World_Cup)
- [Vasco Rossi](http://www.vascorossi.net/it/home/1-0.html)
- Berlin Wall up + down
- [Roberto Benigni](http://www.biography.com/people/roberto-benigni-9207145)
- [Ferrari's victories at F1 Grand Prix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Formula_One_Grand_Prix_winners_%28constructors%29)
- Thai Food
- Star Wars/Trek
- Nirvana (Band)
- Rocky (Rocky II?)
- Troubleman (Soundtrack)

[image: Italian edition]

---

### Australia and New Zealand

- [AC/DC](http://www.acdc.com)
- [Space Travel](http://www.mtatravel.com.au/space)
- [Steve Irwin](http://www.crocodilehunter.com.au/crocodile_hunter/about_steve_terri/)
- [Skippy the Bush Kangaroo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060025/)
- [Tim Tams](http://www.arnotts.com.au/our-products/products/arnotts-tim-tam.aspx)
- Thai Food
- Star Wars/Trek
- Nirvana (Band)
- Rocky (Rocky II?)
- Troubleman (Soundtrack)

[image: Australian edition]

---

### Russia

- [Yuri Gagarin](http://www.russianarchives.com/gallery/gagarin/)
- [Vladamir Vystoskiy](http://www.kulichki.com/vv/eng/)
- [Soviet Union Dissolution - 1991](http://www.history.com/topics/cold-war/fall-of-soviet-union)
- [Moscow doesn't believe in tears](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079579/)
- Disco
- Thai Food
- Star Wars/Trek
- Nirvana (Band)
- Rocky (Rocky II?)
- Troubleman (Soundtrack)

[image: Russian edition]

---

### France

- [France 98](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_FIFA_World_Cup)
- [Louis de Funès](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_de_Fun%C3%A8s)
- [Coluche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coluche)
- [Daft Punk](http://www.daftpunk.com)
- [The Fifth Element](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119116/)
- Thai Food
- Star Wars/Trek
- Nirvana (Band)
- Rocky (Rocky II?)
- Troubleman (Soundtrack)

[image: French edition]

---

### Brazil

- [Ayrton Senna](http://www.formula1.com/teams_and_drivers/hall_of_fame/45/)
- [Wagner Moura](http://oficialwagnermoura.blogspot.com/)
- [Xuxa](http://xuxa.globo.com/paginas/index/13/Biography)
- [Mamonas Assassinas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamonas_Assassinas)
- [Chaves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Ch%C3%A1vez)
- Thai Food
- Star Wars/Trek
- Nirvana (Band)
- Rocky (Rocky II?)
- Troubleman (Soundtrack)

[image: Brazil edition]

---

### Germany

- [Currywurst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currywurst)
- Moon Landing
- Berlin Wall up + down
- [Oktoberfest](http://www.oktoberfest.de/en/)
- Disco
- Thai Food
- Star Wars/Trek
- Nirvana (band)
- Rocky (Rocky II?)
- Troubleman (soundtrack)

[image: German edition]

---

Comment: I find it interesting that the handwriting varies from one region to the next.

Comment: In all universes, Steve Rogers wants to try out Thai Food.

Comment: Also, the hand writing style looks the same, but the slight difference in each iteration tells me they actually had him write it out for each release, or at the very least had someone who could mimick his handwriting write it out for each release.

Comment: @Zibbobz Look at "Disco" between the US and Korean versions. In general, his capital D's change from one to the next. It's also odd that the "Berlin Wall" changes from "Berlin Wall Up + Down" in the US to "Berlin Wall up + down" (no parenthesis) in Italy.

Comment: @Zibbobz Probably neither his handwriting or his hands in those screenshots, to be honest. Simple things like that they're not going to bother to get the actual actor to do.

Comment: The "Spanish" one definitely means Spain.  The first five items are all from Spain.

Comment: Troubleman (soundtrack)?

Comment: @RobertF Cap is advised to listen to the soundtrack for [Trouble Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069414/) during the course of the movie. The screencaps come from the scene where he adds it to his list.

Comment: @phantom42 - Cool, thanks.

Comment: As an Australian, I'm sad we couldn't have 5 things worth listing and had "Space travel" as filler in the list.

Comment: It says 10 including Germany, but you list 10 lists excluding Germany.

Comment: @unor, Yes. I just quoted EW. I'm still looking for a screencap for full evidence of the Germany list

Comment: Star Wars/ Trek is common... Does he want to watch all movies and TV shows?

Comment: Curiously, in South Africa, we got the US list.

Comment: not for India or atleast Asia :(

Comment: I was really hoping David Hasselhoff would be on the German list... :( Great answer btw @phantom42

Comment: Though you could find a justification, some of them look out of character and poor fan service.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I'm amused that Tim Tams made the list

Comment: In the US version I read "Pisco" instead of "Disco", which is a famous Peruvian alcoholic beverage, most well known for its cocktail form "Pisco Sour".

Comment: Can confirm that Louis de Funes is a cultural icon you do not wish to miss. Closest comparison would be Britain's John Cleese.