# Why is "Star Wars" crossed out on Steve's list?

Tags: star-wars, marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, Steve has a list of things people have recommended he catch up on.

[image: Cap's list]

On the American, and presumably most canon, version, "Star Wars" appears to be crossed out. It also appears to be the *only* thing crossed out on the list. It [isn't](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/53807/51226) crossed out on any of the other international versions.

Has anyone associated with the movie commented on why this is?

- Did Steve decide *Star Wars* wasn't worth watching?
- Has Steve already watched *Star Wars* and thus checked it off?
- Is it just a random, unintentional pen mark?
- Is it something else?

Additionally, do we by any chance know why it wasn't crossed out on the other versions of the list?

Comment: Hmmm. I recall some lines where he mentioned that he *did* get a reference. I don't think it was SW related, though.

Comment: @CreationEdge In *The Avengers* he understands a *Wizard of Oz* reference.

Comment: I thought that was it, but mixed up movies. Oh well!

Comment: I just want to know if *The Winter Soldier*'s had  a Trekkie Agenda the entire time.

Comment: The stroke is lighter than the one used for the slash between Star Wars and Trek and I would expect a deliberate line to be more horizontal. With that plus the fact that the other versions don’t have Star Wars crossed out, I’m guessing that it’s an unintentional pen stroke.

Comment: @RogueJedi - *Wizard of Oz* (the movie) came out in 1937, I think.  The book was presumably older than that.

Comment: @WadCheber you've just made my day with "presumably".

Comment: I guess Steve has to uncross Star Wars now that TFA is out

Comment: Wasn´t that a joke resp. a nerd cookie to the star wars/Star Trek preferences of most viewers? If that#s he case it's trash, since there should be Babylon 5 or firefly

Comment: I think it was a joke, and the joke being, "EVERYONE (even those frozen in Ice for decades) has seen Star Wars. :)

Comment: None of the items were crossed out in the other (regional) versions of the lists; http://comicsalliance.com/captain-america-the-winter-soldier-movie-international-list-differences/

Comment: Perhaps it should be an underline for Thai Food?

Comment: He has also seen "War Games".

Comment: @user64875 Personally, I haven't seen Star Wars.

Comment: He crossed it out to avoid the Samuel L Jackson paradox.

Comment: He watched it, I guess

Comment: Because Tony made him watch it, quoting the entire movie.

Comment: I assume this was just product placement by Disney. What movie does the coolest superhero around see before watching the moon landing? Star Wars!

Comment: @user14111 It is. There was just a typo.

Comment: It's a shopping list for Disney.

Answer (score 4):

There appears to be no official sources, but it's likely a nod to the fact that Disney owns Marvel and Star Wars. It would make sense to have it be the only thing crossed off the list as presumably having been done.

The fact that it's one of the few things that's in all the international lists would support this.

Answer (score 0):

I saw an article that Cap was a Star Wars fan and didnt like Star Trek, besides the obvious that Marvel is owned by the mouse it would be logical for him to watch Star Wars first because at the time there were only 7 movies compaired to the 10 Trek movies and all the series he would have to watch to catch up.

Comment: Where did you read this article regarding Cap not liking _Star Trek_...? Assuming it was online, adding the relevant link to your answer would greatly improve it.